# como acceder user admin en postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

Acabo de instalar Postgres 12 con PgAdmin4 en Ubuntu, instale normal y estoy accediendo con el usuario postgres pero veo en la raiz del PgAdmin hay un server llamado localhost, cuando quiero acceder a ese localhost me pide contraseña del usuario(user) 'admin'.
Este usuario viene por defecto ?
Cual es su contraseña ? o que archivo del postgres tengo que modificar para acceder al localhost

adjunto imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ese usuarui no viene por defecto, puede ser una conexion antigua u otro detalle

Comment: Si fuese una conexión antigua como lo lo puedo eliminar ??

Comment: Creo que desde el pgadmin puedes dar click derecho a la conexión y ver qué opciones tiene